# Datatable sorting based on radio buttons and checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using JQuery datatables and, there is a require to sort two columns which has radio button and checkbox. Datatables sort on the basis of values , so i am not able to sort on checkbox and radio button checked and unchecked values.

hbs

```
<table id="team-members-data">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>{{Name}}</th>
        <th>{{Age}}</th>
        <th>{{RadioButton Column}}</th>
        <th>{{Checkbox column}}</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

js file

```
var teamMembers = $('#team-members-data').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "order": [[ 3, 'asc' ], [ 2, 'asc' ],[ 1, 'asc' ], [ 0, 'asc' ]]
});
```

I am trying to get sorting on the basis of checkbox and radio button as well. Let me know , how it can be done.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use custom sorting functions, see [Custom data source sorting](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/#Custom-data-source-sorting) and [Checkbox data source](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/custom-data-source/dom-checkbox).

```js
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-checkbox'] = function  ( settings, col )
{
    return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
        return $('input', td).prop('checked') ? '1' : '0';
    } );
};

$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-text'] = function  ( settings, col )
{
    return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
        return $('input', td).val();
    } );
};

var teamMembers = $('#team-members-data').DataTable({
   "columnDefs": [
      {
         "targets": 2,
         "orderDataType": "dom-text"
      }, {
         "targets": 3,
         "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox"
      }
   ],
   "order": [[ 3, 'asc' ], [ 2, 'asc' ],[ 1, 'asc' ], [ 0, 'asc' ]]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Gyrocode.  Your answer was very helpful.  Here is an implementation of `dom-radio`.

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-radio'] = function ( settings, col ) {
    return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
        return $('input[type=radio]:checked', td).val();
    } );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-radio'] = function ( settings, col ) {
    return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
        return $('input', td)[1].checked ? '1' : '0';
    } );
};
```