# How to display a row with selected radio button as a first row in the datatable when the table is repopulated and not when clicking on the column

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

I'm populating a datatable based on the service call with the following code:

```
    Web.Services.MyService.GetNotes(myObject.ID, function (result) {
        Notes = [];
        for (var ctr = 0; ctr < result.length; ctr++) {
            var item = result[ctr];
            var checked = ' ';
            if (item.Important) checked = "checked";
            var id = item.ID;

            Notes[Notes.length] =
                [
                    '<input type="radio" id =' + item.ID + ' name = "priorityMessage" class="importantNoteCheck" ' + checked + ' ">',
                    item.CreatedDate.toString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"),
                    item.CreatedBy,
                    item.CategoryName == null ? '' : item.CategoryName,
                    item.Note,
                    item.ApplicationName,
                ];
        }
        $('#tblNotes').dataTable().fnClearTable();
        if (Notes.length > 0)
            $('#tblNotes').dataTable().fnAddData(Notes);
        $(".updateNote").addClass('ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget');
        $(".updateNote").css('margin-top', '25px');
```

And the datatable is declared as following:

```
 $("#tblNotes").dataTable(
    {
         "sDom": 't<"fg-toolbar ui-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-bl ui-corner-br ui-helper-clearfix"i>',
        //sDom:             
        //'l' - Length changing
        //'f' - Filtering input
        //'t' - The table!
        //'i' - Information
        //'p' - Pagination
        //'r' - pRocessing
         //"bAutoWidth": false,
         "aoColumns": [
             { "sSortDataType": "dom-checkbox"}, //checkbox
             { "sType": "string", "bSortable": true}, //CreatedDate 
             { "sType": "string", "bSortable": true}, //CreatedBy 
             { "sType": "string", "bSortable": true }, //Category 
             { "sType": "string", "bSortable": false}, //Note   
             { "sType": "string", "bSortable": true} //Application
             //{ "sType": "string", "bSortable": false} //Update Button
         ],
         "sScrollY": "180px",
           "bPaginate": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "aaSorting": [],
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bInfo": true,
         "bJQueryUI": true,
    });
```

This is the partial section of a generated html code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td><input type="radio" id="43966" name="priorityMessage" class="importantNoteCheck" checked="" "=""></td>
        <td>05/24/2022 12:46:00</td>
        <td>eugene.gruzin</td>
        <td>Debit Attempt</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>EMRS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
        <td><input type="radio" id="43987" name="priorityMessage" class="importantNoteCheck" "=""></td>
        <td>05/24/2022 12:45:39</td>
        <td>eugene.gruzin</td>
        <td>Action Alert</td>
        <td>Important Note 3 - JC Decor</td>
        <td>EMRS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td><input type="radio" id="50540" name="priorityMessage" class="importantNoteCheck" "=""></td>
        <td>05/24/2022 09:54:12</td>
        <td>eugene.gruzin</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Adding new note</td>
        <td>EMRS</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

The pop up allows add new Note that can be Important or just a Regular note.
To mark it as important, I need to select a checkbox before adding the record into a `database`.

I also can update make a note as important by selected a `radio button` on the row.

Then when updating the record, the table is repopulated ordered by Created Date, which in case of update, will be displayed on top, since the sort by Created Date.

When the pop up opens, the data is displayed ordered by Created Date as well, since that's how it's returned from a database.

However, when I'm adding the new record, and don't mark it as important, the `datatable` gets repopulated with a new record on top (sorted by Created Date) and the previously note marked as important is not on top anymore.

How can I make sure that when table is repopulated after adding a regular (not important note), the previously created record is on top?

There can be only one important note in the table

Comment: Does this provide an approach to help answer your question: [Datatable sorting based on radio buttons and checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36931783/12567365). Or the approach shown here: [jQuery DataTable Order Table Based On Checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46590217/12567365), but changed to use radio buttons?

Comment: Thank you. This won't work in my case, since I don't sort it by clicking on the column. 
I used that approach before, when I needed to sort it by the column.

But now, the requirements has changed, and I'm looking for the solution on how to repopulate a table so that's sorted automatically when repopulated

Comment: Thank you for the updates. (a) What is the pop-up you mention? I don't see a pop-up in the question's code. (b) What version of DataTables are you using? I ask because the question uses [deprecated names](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert). (c) The customized sorting approach does not require the user to click on a heading - you can use the `order` and/or `orderFixed` options, for example.

Comment: I have a pop up where the datatable is populated. Pop up has "Add Note" and "Update" buttons. The pop up is opened and populated by  a datatable when another button on a main screen is clicked, calling the service that returns the data ordered by Create Date. 

However, as soon as a new node is created and it's not the important one, it still has Created Date as a column the data is sorted by. That's why, I want to show selected row first. 

As far as the version of datatable, it's 1.10.21

Comment: Understood. Thank you again. I do believe the code in the linked question(s) will help you to get what you want.

Comment: You mean "deprecated names" link? And which one should work with radio buttons value? As I understand that should only work if there is a text to sort.
And how should I define an order type in the datatable definition I have?